# How can I call a classmethod from another class in python?

Tags: python, django-models, class-method, edx

I'm programming an app for the edXproyect using Django and I need to retrieve some information from auth_user table and I don't know how to do it. I have this:

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Recomendacion(models.Model):

    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='username', primary_key=True)
    recurso = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column='next_module')

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.usuario.username)
```

#### admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from recomendador.models import Recomendacion

class RecomendacionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fields = ['usuario', 'recurso']
    list_display = ['usuario', 'recurso']

admin.site.register(Recomendacion, RecomendacionAdmin)
```

But I would like to display something like:

```
list_display = ['id', 'usuario', 'full_name', 'recurso']
```

So I have to retrieve the `id` and `full_name` from the `auth_table` with the `username` field. I have tried adding classmethods in Recomendador like:

```
def get_id(self):
    return self.usuario.id
```

and now I want to call them from the `RecomendacionAdmin` class so I can list the `id` and `full_name` fields too but I don't know how to do it. I have googled it but I only get exceptions and errors with the solutions I find. Can anyone help me with this? I'm new to python...

Answer (score 0):

Having a bit of trouble being 100% sure what you are looking for due to the source code not being English, but if you are looking to obtain data about `Recomendacion` inside of `admin.py`, since you are already importing `Recomendacion`, you should just be able to do the following:

```
recomendacion = Recomendacion.objects.get(username=desired_username)
```

That will give you the object who's username is whatever you are looking for, and then you can just access the `id` and `full_name` fields.